# Eclipse Team Foundation Server plugin (Team Explorer Everywhere) null on Check-in

Tags: eclipse, tfs, azure-devops

I have been using the TFS plugin for eclipe for quite some time with my current employer.  Recently, however, I have been getting an error any time I try to check-in any changes I have made to a project.

When I try to check-in my project, the project is validated and then the chick-in process begins.  However, after a short amount of time (sometimes immediately) the process will end.  The only message in the console is `null`.

I checked the TFS log files and there is no error output.  The only indication of error is the `null` displayed in the eclipse console and the fact that none of my files are being checked in.

I have already tried clearing the TFS plugin cache as well as trying to check-in files to a completely clean repository.  The error occurs when trying to check in any of my projects.